# Error: Assets/beandefine.cs(23,1) (sorry Dani) Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I get this error so much! It is not the filename though, because it is **beandefine.cs** (I want to define a GameObject)

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class beandefine : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void BEAN()
    {
            public var BeanPlayer = GameObject.BeanPlayer;
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP. I think the code is good, but it is not working. Verified 3 times and yep, still good. So no idea what is happening, but it doesn't want to work. Thanks for help.

Comment: We have no idea what "not working" means because you haven't defined what the expected behaviour is nor told us any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When will people stop making class level variables inside methods and wondering why the compiler says no?  Apparently not today.

Problem is here

`void BEAN() { public var BeanPlayer = GameObject.BeanPlayer; }`

What do you actually want? If you want the variable at class level, then you need it outside the method. If you only need it in the method drop the public. And BeanPlayer will throw an error as GameObject has no knowledge of such people things. Did you mean to use getcomponent?

Comment: I didnt use gamecomponet, but thanks! Would want it public, so bye!

Comment: i know the answer: instead of BeanPlayer being in void() BEAN {}, i should put it in public class beandefine : MonoBehaviour {}

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put `public var BeanPlayer = GameObject.BeanPlayer;` in

```
public class beandefine : MonoBehaviour {

}
```